# Media query breaking site

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, umbraco

I have a code for a bootstrap carousel I am deploying to a site. It works perfect on large devices but I wanted to add media queries to optimize it for mobile.

However, whenever I add a media query to the style sheet I get a runtime error and the site breaks.

I am using Umbraco and this the carousel is a partial view. When I add in even a blank query such as

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  body {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

I get the runtime error, what could be problem?

Thank you

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: I added a code sample

Comment: You are mixing a CSS media query with a Javascript alert. You should put CSS into the media query to change styles, or measure the window width via Javascript to alert something based on that.
A working media query for you to test out would be: 
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  body {color: red !important;}
}

Answer (score 1):

Since your CSS is within a  tag in your view and you're using @media, you must escape the @, by adding an additional @. So change your code to

```
@@media screen and (max-width:480px)
```

When using @ the compiler thinks you're writing Razor code and it simply errors because it can't figure out what @media is supposed to be, since there's no variable defined with its name. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you change it to this does it work?

```
@@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  body {
    color: red;
  }
}
```